# React Native crashes after upgrade to version 0.56. Possible Babel issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, upgrade, babeljs

After upgrading my React Native project using `react-native-git-upgrade` I get the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindings' of null
    at Scope.moveBindingTo (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/scope/index.js:978:13)
    at BlockScoping.updateScopeInfo (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:364:17)
    at BlockScoping.run (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:330:12)
    at PluginPass.BlockStatementSwitchStatementProgram (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/lib/index.js:70:24)
    at newFn (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:237:21)
    at NodePath._call (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:65:20)
    at NodePath.call (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:100:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/jan/Startup/react-native/ordersome/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:142:16)
```

It seems like this problem has something to do with babel. I restarted metro as well as my simulator, but that did not change a thing. Also here are all the packages I've installed that have anything to do with babel (package.json):

```
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.5",
"babel-jest": "23.2.0",
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
```

And here is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

I generated the project using `react-native init` when it was still at 0.55.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try to update the version for`babel-preset-react-native` in your package.json like so:

`"babel-preset-react-native": "^5"`.

Comment: I will just accept this as an answer, but I fixed it another way. I created a new project using `react-native init` and copied all my code there :(

Comment: React-Native 0.56 needs ```babel-preset-react-native``` 5.0.0, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20042.

Comment: FWIW I needed a restart before the error cleared out once upgrading babel-preset-react-native

Comment: `npm i babel-preset-react-native --save-dev` to upgrade

Comment: run `yarn add babel-preset-react-native@5.0.0 --dev` If you continue to see yarn try to install 4.0.0

Comment: For the latecomers from google upgrading to expo-cli and react-native 59, along with this make sure to delete the old `.babelrc` and replace it with the new `babel.config.js`, on top of that make sure it is using the right preset and then follow the instructions expo-cli gives to you to clean watchman and the compilation caches.

Answer (score 1):

According the [babel-preset-react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-native) entry on npmjs.org, it is obsolete. [metro-react-native-babel-preset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/metro-react-native-babel-preset) is the replacement.